# HTML/CSS: Keeping Divs at same height

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if there is any solution for my problem. I have a content-div and a menu-div. The more text there is in the content-div the more it expands. I want my menu-div to follow the content-div as it expands/collapses.

I've tried everything I could think of, but since I'm a beginner maybe I've missed something simple. I haven't found anything on google, only JS-solutions but there have to be a CSS solution to this right?

Heres a fiddle with code: http://jsfiddle.net/YxF9e/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do it with CSS only.
You could have an imaginary height of the right sidebar by adding background image to the wrapper. This could give the impression that the border goes 100% height.

If you want to do this with jQuery, here's the code you need:

```
var contentHeight = $('#content').height();
$('#menu').height(contentHeight);
```

Here's the updates jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/YxF9e/1/

Comment: May I ask you how to implement this in my code? If I want a .JS-file. When i try to do it and use <script src="yourScript.js"> the only thing that happens is that the menu-div goes to the far right of the page. Doesn't work with a button onclick="methodName()" either. Thanks

Comment: In your `head` section, include jQuery library. Then create a javascript file called script.js (or whatever you wanna call it), include this .js file after jQuery. Open your .js file and in there, paste this: [http://pastebin.com/gG3qHBzJ](http://pastebin.com/gG3qHBzJ)

Comment: Sorry, back again. There seems to be some sort of problem with my JS include... Seems that my js files aren't imported correctly..
http://pastebin.com/JepUVtYG

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [Columns of Equal Height](http://css-tricks.com/7692-fluid-width-equal-height-columns/).